# Can't launch my first Java program by jar file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, launch

I just made my first Java program and it worked perfectly, when I launched it by 'IDEA'. Then I wanted to create an executable file to launch it separately. 'IDEA' helped me create a jar file with this content inside it:

1. Some classes (*.class files).
2. Folder META-INF with MANIFEST.MF in it. MANIFEST.MF has only 2
   lines: version info and "Main-Class: ru.nikolski.2048.main".

When I double click on the jar file, nothing happens. When I launch the jar file by 'IDEA', it writes the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -jar C:\Users\Osn\IdeaProjects\Game2048\out\artifacts\Game2048_jar\Game2048.jar

Error: Could not find or load main class ru.nikolski.2048.main
```

I tried to make folder ru/nikolski/2048 inside the jar file, and put all *.class files in it, but it didnt help, I got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe try opening the windows `dos` command prompt (`cmd.exe`) and then run the command `java -jar C:\Users\Osn\IdeaProjects\Game2048\out\artifacts\Game2048_jar\Game2048.jar`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried it, but got the same error in the dos window ('could not find or load main class').

Comment: Ok sorry, I'm not professional with java, I try suggest. What version java? in same dos window what do you have for `java -version`?

Comment: "ru.nikolski.2048.main" is not a valid package name. I bet that if the manifest changes to ...Game2048... (the most likely package name) it will work

Comment: davedwards, the version is 1.8.0_151 (in dos window).

Comment: efekctive, thank you for your comment. The MANIFEST.MF had a line which identified the main class. I tried to replace with 'Game2048' and with 'Game2048.main', but got the same error ('Could not find or load main class Game2048.main').

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem just correcting the line in MANIFEST.MF:

```
Main-Class: Main
```

as my class with main method has the name 'Main'.